# Why is a local var not available in an Angular2 Component from the Chrome debugger?

Tags: angular, typescript

I just wasted a few hours on this, but I want to understand why.

I was importing Lodash into my angular2 project and it was not available in my component when I inspected from a breakpoint in the Chrome debugger.  But then I used it in a `console.log('lodash version:', _.VERSION);` statement, and magically it was there (all along?). And now it is visible in the Chrome debugger.

What is happening behind the scenes here?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ionicBootstrap, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';

import { HomePage } from './pages/home/home';

import * as _ from "lodash";
console.log('0. lodash version:', _.VERSION);
/* 
 * _ is available here in the Chrome debugger 
 */

@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    /*
     * _ is NOT available here in Chrome debugger unless I uncomment line below
     * VM1073:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined(…)
     */
    // console.log('1. lodash version:', _.VERSION);
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }
}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

Comment: But why are you importing it if you don't use it? Probably the compiler doesn't load it if it is not used and then the debugger doesn't find it

Comment: my first time with Typescript.  I was just poking around to see if different things worked, and it was easier to do it ad-hoc in the debugger. But I suppose now I know that is not how it works...